# png image mime type error cakephp

Tags: php, image, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, mime-types

I have a plugin in a cakephp application located at `app/plugins/my_plugin` in which I have a webroot folder which contains some images in the `app/plugins/my_plugin/webroot/img/` folder. I'm trying to put an image as the background of a span in one of the views of `my_plugin`. My span is for example:

```
<span class="my_span"><p>Content...</p></span>
```

And the css I use to but the image as background is:

```
.my_span
{
    background-image:url('<?php echo $this->Html->image('/my_plugin/img/my_image.png', array('alt' => 'My Image'))?>');
}
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

But the weird thing is, when I just try to put the image within my span tags (without putting it as a background through CSS) like:

```
<span class="my_span"><p><?php echo $this->Html->image('/my_plugin/img/my_image.png', array('alt' => 'My Image'))?></p></span>
```

My image displays just fine and I don't have any errors.

Can anybody tell me why I can't put the image as background of my span?

**NOTE**: I already tried `display:block;` or everything else for my span

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that this code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/my_plugin/img/my_image.png', array('alt' => 'My Image'))?>
```

produces this

```
<img src="/my_plugin/img/my_image.png" alt="My Image" />
```

In your case you want to use this code:

```
.my_span
{
    background-image:url(/my_plugin/img/my_image.png);
}
```

Reference: [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1441/image)